# HTML: How to color values in a row of a table according to a certain value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, mongodb

TO start with, I already asked the same question hours ago but got one answer that wasn't helpful at all. My question died since then(same number of views for hours). 
I have a mongodb collection and I'm using node.js . I have a collection for "clothes" and I represent the data of it in this table :

```
 <h2>Clothes</h2>       
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th>price</th>
        <th> date </th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <% for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){%>
        <% if(result[i].type == "price"){%>
        <tr>

            <td><%= result[i].price %></td>
            <td><%= result[i].date %></td>
            <td>
                <form action="/delete-price" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= result[i]._id %>">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <%}%>
        <%}%>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Date can be any day of the week . My question is , I want to make the user submit a certain budget through a form(which is easy) , but I want at the same time to compare all the expenses of all the rows to it

The table is working and fully functional as well as the database.

An example:

```
    Ex: If the user enters budget of 200$ , I should go to all the rows in 

"Clothes" , check the prices, if the prices is greater than the budget, this 

row should be flagged .`
```

How can I achieve this? I'm very new to this . I tried to do this in html and css but this is where my knowledge stops

Comment: you want the switching value to be an attribute of the row instead of just a form input. once it's on the row, you can loop rows, compare the attrib to a value, and set the row's css to indicate state.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer

Comment: Reposting the same question is not recommended.  See [this Meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7054/349827) for better ways to get your question more attention (and hopefully some answers).

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole bunch of ways to solve this. The most trivial way and in line with the rest of your code should be as simple as changing your above code from:

```
    <% if(result[i].type == "price"){%>
    <tr>
```

to

```
    <% if(result[i].type == "price"){%>
    <tr<% if(result[i].price > your_user_input_value_goes_here){%> style="background-color:red"<%}%>>
```